# How to query count of one to one relations in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a postgresql database table design created by object oriented.

```
Accunt (id, CreateDate)
PersonalAccount (AccountId, FirstName, LastName, Phone)
CorporateAccount (AccountId, CorporationName, NationalTaxNumber)
```

`PersonalAccount` and `CorporateAccount` have `AccountId` columns related to `Account` table.

How can I create one to one relation in postgresql?

I have 3 records in Accunt table. 2 of is `PersonalAccount` and 1 of is `CorporateAccount`.

How can I select count group by PersonalAccount and CorporateAccount?

```
AccountType        Count
------------------------
PersonalAccount      2
CorporateAccount     1
Total                3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One method is `union all` and `grouping sets`:

```
select coalesce(accounttype, 'Total'), count(*)
from ((select 'Personal' as accounttype
       from PersonalAccount
      ) union all
      (select 'Corporate'
       from CorporateAccount
      )
     ) pc
group by grouping sets ( (accounttype), () );
```